# ZF2: How to always show a stack trace

Tags: zend-framework2

With ZF2 I get a stack trace when something goes wrong, but for learning purposes I'd sometime like to see a stack trace when things go right. Can I make a call to something that will poop out a stack trace on the page regardless of errors?

Also, are there any good tutorials on reading\understanding the stack traces? Sorry for the double question, but didn't think my second question deserved its own post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate similar information that would be available when an exception is thrown using [`debug_backtrace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php).

In a ZF2 app this might give you *too much* information (and it is also in array format). I wrote a very simple function that I just chucked into my `local.php` to aid debugging; it might be of some help.

```
function debug_light_trace()
{
    $backtrace = "Backtrace :-\n";
    $debug_backtrace = debug_backtrace();

    array_shift($debug_backtrace);

    foreach ($debug_backtrace as $trace) {
        $class      = (isset($trace['class']))?$trace['class']:'';
        $function   = (isset($trace['function']))?$trace['function']:'';
        $file       = (isset($trace['file']))?$trace['file']:'';
        $APP_ROOT   = dirname(dirname(__DIR__));
        $file       = str_replace($APP_ROOT, '', $file);
        $line       = (isset($trace['line']))?$trace['line']:'';
        $backtrace .= "{$file}({$line}) - {$class}::{$function}()\n";
    }
    return $backtrace;
}
```

With regards to more information, [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) would be a good place to start (and of Google searching). I *very quickly* scanned  this [tuts plus guide](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-php-exceptions--net-22274); which  might also give you some more background.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [ZendDeveloperTools](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendDeveloperTools)

It's a great help for developer.

Comment: I have ZendDeveloperTools, but how do I make it show a stack trace?